# Parsing youtube url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I've written a ruby youtube url parser.  It's designed to take an input of a youtube url of one of the following structures (these are currently the youtube url structures that I could find, maybe there's more?):

```
http://youtu.be/sGE4HMvDe-Q
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp7E973zozc&feature=relmfu
http://www.youtube.com/p/A0C3C1D163BE880A?hl=en_US&#038;fs=1
```

The aim is to save just the id of the clip or playlist so that it can be embedded,  so if it's a clip:  `'sGE4HMvDe-Q'`,  or if it's a playlist:  `'p/A0C3C1D163BE880A'`

The parser I wrote works fine for these urls,  but seems a bit brittle and long-winded,  I'm just wondering if someone could suggest a nicer ruby approach to this problem?

```
def parse_youtube
    a = url.split('//').last.split('/')
    b = a.last.split('watch?v=').last.split('?').first.split('&').first
    if a[1] == 'p'
        url = "p/#{b}"
    else
        url = b
    end
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
def parse_youtube url
   regex = /(?:.be\/|\/watch\?v=|\/(?=p\/))([\w\/\-]+)/
   url.match(regex)[1]
end

urls = %w[http://youtu.be/sGE4HMvDe-Q 
          http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp7E973zozc&feature=relmfu
          http://www.youtube.com/p/A0C3C1D163BE880A?hl=en_US&fs=1]

urls.each {|url| puts parse_youtube url }
# sGE4HMvDe-Q
# Lp7E973zozc
# p/A0C3C1D163BE880A
```

Depending on how you use this, you might want a better validation that the URL is indeed from youtube.

**UPDATE**:

Coming back to this a few years later. I've always been annoyed by how sloppy the original answer was. Since the validity of the Youtube domain wasn't validated anyway, I've removed some of the slop.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    be                       'be'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    watch                    'watch'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \?                       '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    v=                       'v='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\/\-]+                any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '\/', '\-' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: This is good - thank you. Any suggestions on how to change the regex to handle httpS:// prefixes as well?

Comment: Simply change the `http` for `https?`.

Comment: Thanks Vache - I was wondering if the regex could be modified to handle both http and https in the same method.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying too. The `?` is part of the regex. See  [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) to see what the `?` is all about. You should pick up some basic regex, it's not complicated and it will help you ! ;)

Comment: This is the best explanation of a regex I have ever seen. Nice.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Addressable gem, you can save yourself *some* work.  There's also a URI module in stdlib, but Addressable is more powerful.

```
require 'addressable/uri'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse(youtube_url)
if uri.path == "/watch"
  uri.query_values["v"] if uri.query_values
else
  uri.path
end
```

EDIT | Removed madness.  Didn't notice Addressable provides `#query_values` already.

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

urls = %w[http://youtu.be/sGE4HMvDe-Q 
          http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp7E973zozc&feature=relmfu
          http://www.youtube.com/p/A0C3C1D163BE880A?hl=en_US&fs=1]

def parse_youtube url
  u = URI.parse url
  if u.path =~ /watch/
    p CGI::parse(u.query)["v"].first
  else
    p u.path
  end
end

urls.each { |url| parse_youtube url }
#=> "/sGE4HMvDe-Q"
#=> "Lp7E973zozc"
#=> "/p/A0C3C1D163BE880A"
```