# Get youtube video id from html code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, youtube

I have html like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Wa6CA3YqV2Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How do i get video id `Wa6CA3YqV2Q` with regex? And are there any other ways to achieve this?

UPD: 
I have used Nokogiri, and i managed to get `http://www.youtube.com/embed/Wa6CA3YqV2Q`, so how do i get id, of video having this link?

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041352/extract-and-replace-youtube-only-iframe-src?rq=1 hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended with following

```
string = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/Wa6CA3YqV2Q'

result =  string.split('/').last
```

Answer (score 5):

The code below will take any vimeo or youtube URL and return the video ID and the provider.

In your model

```
def parse_video_url(url)
    @url = url

    youtube_formats = [
        %r(https?://youtu\.be/(.+)),
        %r(https?://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=(.*?)(&|#|$)),
        %r(https?://www\.youtube\.com/embed/(.*?)(\?|$)),
        %r(https?://www\.youtube\.com/v/(.*?)(#|\?|$)),
        %r(https?://www\.youtube\.com/user/.*?#\w/\w/\w/\w/(.+)\b)
      ]

    vimeo_formats = [%r(https?://vimeo.com\/(\d+)), %r(https?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+))]  

    @url.strip!

    if @url.include? "youtu"
      youtube_formats.find { |format| @url =~ format } and $1
      @results = {provider: "youtube", id: $1}
      @results
    elsif @url.include? "vimeo"  
      vimeo_formats.find { |format| @url =~ format } and $1
      @results = {provider: "vimeo", id: $1}
      @results
    else
      return nil # There should probably be some error message here
    end  
end
```

Then in your controller just call:

```
@results = @course.parse_video_url(@course.video_url)
# Access the hash with @results[:provider] or @results [:id]
```

And in your view you can write an IF statement to display the relevant embed code for the provider/id combo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
string.scan(/src="\S+\/(\w+)"/)[0][0]
```

but if you're doing a lot of html work i would recommend using a full-on HTML parser like Nokogiri or something perhaps more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

While you might be able to parse it with a regex, parsing arbitrary html with regexs is bad unless you really know what you're doing. There's a lot of historical controversy around the subject, search about it if you're interested.

The proper way is to parse the document, there's a great parser for rails:

http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: used nokogiri, got link, now need to get all symbols after last `/`

Comment: Because Youtube urls can vary a lot, this is not an easy one. Check other answered questions like:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match/6382259#6382259

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556772/parsing-youtube-url

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/Wa6CA3YqV2Q'
regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?\w*\.\w*\/(?:watch\?v=)?((?:p\/)?[\w\-]+)/
match = string.match(regex)
if match
  return match[1]
end
return ''
```

I got it from here and changed it a little bit: [Parsing youtube url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556772/parsing-youtube-url)